# Modelと表示したいColumns指定から、HTMLのTableのTbody用のViewModelを生成する関数

Tags: javascript

どのように実装すればよいでしょうか
言語はjavascript(es6可能)です。
目的は、modelの情報と表示したいcolumn指定から、modelの関連情報(has_manyなものやbelongs_toなもの含め）いい感じにtableタグを出力するためのviewModelを得ることです。

```
// can use es6
function makeTbodyModel(columns, model) {
  // pls implement
}

columns = [ 'name', 'age', { 'friends': [ 'name' ] }, 'gender' ];
model = {
  name: taro,
  age: 8,
  friends: [
    {
      name: jiro,
      age: 7,
      friends: [/*anydata*/],
      gender: male
    },
    {
      name: hanako,
      age: 12,
      friends: [/*anydata*/],
      gender: female
    }
  ],
  gender: male
};

makeTbodyModel(columns, model); /* => 下記の返り値が得られることを期待しています
[
  [
    { value: taro, rowSpan=2 },
    { value: 8,    rowSpan=2 },
    { value: jiro, rowSpan=1 },
    { value: male, rowSpan=2 },
  ],
  [
    { value: hanako rowSpan=1 },
  ]
] */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

しばらく自分で頑張ってみた結果、完全ではないですが実装できたので書いておきます。
すこし、質問のときとテストデータやメソッド名が違いますが、本質は変わらないのでそのまま掲載します.

```
// 非破壊のinsert
// returns insertされたあとのarray
function arrayInserted(array, toIndex, ...elements) {
  let clone = array.concat([]);
  clone.splice(toIndex, 0, ...elements);
  return clone;
}

function buildTRecordsForOneModel(columns, model) {
  let attrs = columns.filter(e => e.constructor == String).map(e => {
    return {value: model[e]};
  });
  let hasManyAssoc = columns.filter(e => e.constructor == Object)[0] || null;

  let hasManyModels; 
  let recordsForOneModel;
  if(hasManyAssoc != null) {
    let assocName = Object.keys(hasManyAssoc)[0];
    let subColumns = hasManyAssoc[assocName];
    hasManyModels = buildTRecordsForManyModels(subColumns, model[assocName]);
    recordsForOneModel = hasManyModels.map((record, index) => {
      if(index === 0) {
        attrs.forEach(attr => {
          attr.rowSpan = hasManyModels.length
        });
        return arrayInserted(attrs, columns.indexOf(hasManyAssoc), ...record);
      }else {
        return record;
      }
    });
    //console.log(`recordsForOneModel: ${JSON.stringify(recordsForOneModel)}`);
    if(recordsForOneModel.length === 0) {
      attrs.forEach(attr => attr.rowSpan = 1);
      recordsForOneModel = [arrayInserted(attrs, columns.indexOf(hasManyAssoc), {value: null, rowSpan: 1})];
    }
  }else {
    attrs.forEach(attr => attr.rowSpan = 1);
    recordsForOneModel = [attrs];
  }
  //console.log(`model: ${JSON.stringify(model)}`);
  //console.log(`cols: ${JSON.stringify(columns)}`);
  //console.log(`attrs: ${JSON.stringify(attrs)}`);
  //console.log(`hasManyModels: ${JSON.stringify(hasManyModels)}`);
  //console.log(`recordsForOneModel: ${JSON.stringify(recordsForOneModel)}`);
  return recordsForOneModel;
}

function buildTRecordsForManyModels(columns, models) {
  let recordsForManyModels = [];
  for(let model of models) {
    recordsForManyModels = recordsForManyModels.concat(buildTRecordsForOneModel(columns, model));
  }
  //console.log(`recordsForManyModels: ${JSON.stringify(recordsForManyModels)}`);
  return recordsForManyModels;
}

let columns = [ 'name', 'age', { friends: [ { friends: ['name'] }, 'name' ] }, 'gender' ];
let models = [{
  name: 'taro',
  age: 8,
  friends: [
    {
      name: 'jiro',
      age: 7,
      friends: [],
      gender: 'male'
    },
    {
      name: 'hanako',
      age: 12,
      friends: [
        { name: 'kumiko' }, { name: 'togeko' }
      ],
      gender: 'female'
    }
  ],
  gender: 'male'
}];

let result = buildTRecordsForManyModels(columns, models);

console.log(result.map(i=> i.map(j => JSON.stringify(j)).join(' | ')).join("\n"));
console.log(`html render example -> \n<table>\n${result.map(tr => `  <tr>\n${tr.map(td => `    <td rowspan=${td.rowSpan}>${td.value}</td>`).join("\n")}\n  </tr>`).join("\n")}\n</table>`);
```

実行結果

```
{"value":"taro","rowSpan":3} | {"value":8,"rowSpan":3} | {"value":null,"rowSpan":1} | {"value":"jiro","rowSpan":1} | {"value":"male","rowSpan":3}
{"value":"kumiko","rowSpan":1} | {"value":"hanako","rowSpan":2}
{"value":"togeko","rowSpan":1}
html render example -> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>taro</td>
    <td rowspan=3>8</td>
    <td rowspan=1>null</td>
    <td rowspan=1>jiro</td>
    <td rowspan=3>male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=1>kumiko</td>
    <td rowspan=2>hanako</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=1>togeko</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### 問題点

同階層のモデルに２つ以上のhasMany関連がcolumnsで指定された場合、ｈｔｍｌのtableとしてrendering不可能であると気づきました。よって、hasMany関連は一つまでという制約を課さなくてはいけません。
上記コードはbelongsTo|hasOne関連に対応してません。しかし、対応するとなると、関連先にhasMany関連が指定されている、belongsTo|hasOne関連が複数ある場合も、rendering不可能になってしまうので結構難しそうです。